# is there a way to find in what line that the access is denied in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I only get this message on my iOS app whenever I fail to pass the security rules

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I have 320 lines of code written in the firebase console firestore rules. and whenever I get that error message, it little bit hard to track in what rules that I fail to pass. is there a way to find out in what line that the access is denied in firestore security rules ? I can't find it in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get additional information on what rule failed in your client-side code. This is actually by design, as it would give would-be attackers a lot of additional information to go by.

The quickest way to see what line fails is to reproduce the scenario in the rules simulator in the Firebase console, which **will** show exactly what line is failing.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Frank said, you can get much more detailed information about security rule execution using the [security rules emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) running on your local machine, along with code that implements a test suite.  This is the best way to debug security rules, as you will have comprehensive output describing which rule rejected access.

I strongly recommend using this tool to test locally before deploying rules, so it reduces the chance you might make a mistake that could affect your product.